# How many universality classes are there in the universe?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

There are more-than-we-can-count number of phases in the universe, all described by their interesting symmetries. But what about universality classes? Is the number just as big? Ising, Heisenberg, XY and percolation... there are only a handful of them. Does this small number mean anything? Can we write down a big Lagrangian and say: "Well, this is the allowed number for universality classes." Kind of like the standard model describing forces.

Comment: By universality class, do you mean universality class for critical points (i.e. continuous phase transitions)? There are also infinitely many. For example, for each positive integer $n$, there is a O$(n)$ universality class in 3d ($n=1$ is Ising, $n=2$ is XY, $n=3$ is Heisenberg).

Comment: Yes, mathematically that makes sense. I guess there is no way of knowing if there is an upper bound for physical systems, now that I think about it.

Comment: @benhostder All these O$(n)$ universality classes can be realized physically. The more tractable question is perhaps the following: given some field content and global symmetry, what are the possible universality classes? This can often be answered by writing down the Lagrangian in a derivative expansion, with all terms preserving symmetry, and classify the possible RG fixed points.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to ask! Thank you, I'll think about this.